# Validator not working at all when receving a $request->all()

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel, api

I have a problem, I'm receiving data in my API from a frontend built with Angular, when the API receives the data it validates some values with the Validator library, but the validator library is not working because it's not getting the data from the `$request->all()` because it's always entering to the error condition of `$validateData->fails()` and not returning me the JWT of the successful login.

I would be very grateful if you could help me, down here my code:

Response when returning data from Angular before it's send to the API:

```
Object { userId: "", tipo_documento: "", nombres: "", apellidos: "", direccion: "", correo_electronico: "test123@hotmail.com", contrasena: "Prueba123", telefono: "", celular: "", tipo_Usuario: "", … }
user.service.ts:25:16
```

response when returning $request->all() from the API on Laravel :

```
Object { "{\"userId\":\"\",\"tipo_documento\":\"\",\"nombres\":\"\",\"apellidos\":\"\",\"direccion\":\"\",\"correo_electronico\":\"test123@hotmail_com\",\"contrasena\":\"Prueba123\",\"telefono\":\"\",\"celular\":\"\",\"tipo_Usuario\":\"\",\"ultima_act\":\"\"}": null }
login.component.ts:35:16
```

login method in Laravel:

```
    public function userLogin(Request $request){
        $jwtValidator = new \JwtAuth();

        $validateData = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'correo_electronico' => 'required|email',
            'contrasena' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validateData->fails()){
            return $request->all();
            $signUp = array(
                'status' => 'Error',
                'code' => 404,
                'message' => 'El usuario no se ha podido identificar',
                'errors' => $validateData->errors()
            );

        }else{
            $hashPass = hash('sha256', $request->contrasena);
 
            $signUp = $jwtValidator->signUp($request->correo_electronico, $hashPass);

            if(!empty($request->getToken)){
                $signUp = $jwtAuth->signUp($request->correo_electronico, $hashPass, true); 
            }

        }

        return response()->json($signUp, 200);
    }
```

Login Componen.ts in Angular:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public user: User;
  public status: string;

  constructor( private _userService: UserService ) {

    this.user = new User('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
    this.status = '';

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form: any){
    this._userService.signup(this.user).subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response.status == 'Success') {
          this.status = response.status;
        } else {
          this.status = 'Error';
        }
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        this.status = 'error';
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
      )
  }

}
```

SignUp method in a service from Angular:

```
    signup(user: any, getToken = null): Observable<any>{
        if(getToken != null){
            user.getToken = true;
            console.log(user.getToken);
        }

        let params = user;
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        console.log(params);

        return this._http.post(this.url+'/login', params, {headers: headers});
    }
```

Comment: I think you shoud use in your SignUp method as Content-Type "application/json" instead and share the response if it's still go under the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the return data your email is set to `test123@hotmail_com` which isn't a valid email (notice the underscore). Check the input data again and make sure your email is valid.